# Show that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\left(\frac{d}{2x+2}\right)^d$ is always positive for $x\geq 2$ and $d \in \{2,3,4,5\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

My first instinct was to show that the derivative is always negative for the conditions above and with the limit $=0$ it should follow that it is always positive but it is way to complicated for me. This can be done for every $d$ I consider. I can't find a more direct way.

Comment: Hint: Both terms are positive, so you can rearrange and take the inverse, and then you just have to show that $\left(\dfrac{2x+2}{d}\right)^d>x$.

Comment: Does it help to consider $\left(\dfrac{2x+2}{d}\right)^d-x$ as polynomial and search for roots? It might be possible to do it for each $d$ differently

Answer (score 0):

When the cases are small we can check each case separately. So first substitute d=2 in the function.
$$f(x)=\frac1x-(\frac{2}{2x+2})^2$$
Now find the interval of $x$ for which $f(x)>0$ by solving the inequality:
$$\frac1x-(\frac{2}{2x+2})^2>0$$
$$\frac1x>(\frac{2}{2x+2})^2$$
$$\frac1x>\frac{4}{(2x+2)^2}$$
$$\frac1x>\frac{4}{(2x+2)^2}$$
$$(2x+2)^2>4x$$
$$4x^2+4+8x>4x$$
$$4x^2+4+4x>0$$
$$x^2+1+x>0$$
Which is greater then zero for all $x\epsilon (-\infty,\infty)$,
Similarly you can check cases for $d=3,4,5$.

Comment: I don't think the cases for $x>2$ will be so simple!

Comment: yes those would be more complex.